# Include all javascript files belonging to a folder in laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

Is there a way I could include all the javascript files belonging to a folder, from a .php file in laravel 5.2?

Something along the lines of:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/*.js') !!}"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to achieve your goal:

```
@foreach(Storage::files('/js') as $file)
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset($file) !!}"></script>
@endforeach;
```

This is the first idea that comes to my mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
$list = File::allFiles('/path/to/dir');
foreach ($list as $file)
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . (string)$file . '"></script>
}
```

That'd include all files in a folder. That said, it'd probably be a better idea to create a file such as `includes` or `bootstrap`, where you list any and all files that you should include - and include THAT file instead. More maintainable that way, and if you wish for a file to just be temporarily "disabled", you wouldn't have to *delete* or *move* it.